# How to determine content directory for Dynamics AX 2012 (for helpfile msi)

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, help-system

I have to create an MSI to deploy our help files in Dynamics AX 2012.

The way the help system runs, as I understand, is it (the help system) gets installed on the server, and the normal directory for the content (the help files it serves) is c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dynamicsAX6HelpServer\Content.

The admin, of course, can change it.

Help files are served up from folders under that content directory to Dynamics AX 2012 clients through a web-service.

I now have to create an MSI installer for deploying our help information when our product gets deployed.  The process is just dropping our helpfiles into that content directory (well, our helpfile structure, not just files).  We already have our helpfiles there and it works on our system.

I'm not able to find anything on how I can go about finding where the content directory is.  I can guess and place it at the path above, but that's not the right way to do this.

My intent is to create an MSI with Installshield to deploy the helpfiles.  My experience with Dynamics ranks somewhere between zero and none, so I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring any better answer, I found the directory in the registry under

COMPUTER\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Setup\HelpServer\InstallDir

This solves my issue.